# Performance difference of $ vs. '()'

Tags: haskell

I have 2 code submissions on codeforces -

https://codeforces.com/contest/762/submission/29695191
& https://codeforces.com/contest/762/submission/29695201

both have the exact same code except for the usage of $ vs. () . One with the $ exceeded the time limit on the 6th test and the other passed all the tests.

Any suggestions on why that might be the case?

Answer (score 5):

They're exactly the same. There's just some variance in runtime - your passing test case is within 5% of failing on time as well.